# How to add JWT authentication for Java play framework application

Tags: java, jwt, playframework

I am new to the Java Play framework and I have created API's to handle employee information. I want to secure my API's with JWT authentication.

I am trying to add JWT authentication but I am not able to understand how to start with and not getting any references. Thank you

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You will want to look at Action composition to help drive using JWT authentication. https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/JavaActionsComposition. This https://dzone.com/articles/jwt-authentication-with-play-framework is a few years old and for older version of Play, but the general idea.

Comment: Don't know for sure what you want, but Play! comes with default support for JWT, just create a new session and it will be created as JWT

Comment: Please check this example Controller with login API example producing JWT token and Action protected by checking JWT  Bearer token: https://github.com/ertra/play-framework-by-example/blob/master/app/controllers/APIWithTokenExampleController.java